How do you show Dominating Set is NP Complete
A dominating set of an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ is a subset of
vertices $C\subseteq V$ such that every vertex $v\in V$ either belongs to $C$ or has a neighbor in $C$. The corresponding decision problem is defined as follows:
we are given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and an integer $k\geq 1$, and we need to decide whether $G$ has a dominating set whose size is at most $k$.
I know that it is possible to reduce from the vertex cover problem, but I am not sure how.

Please make sure to show an effort next time -- show your attempts or where you got stuck, so we can help you  understand and not just solve the question for you. I gave you the crux of the proof, it is should be easy to fill the details on your own.

Consider an undirected graph $G = (V, E) $. Assuming that $G$ has no isolated vertices (that is,  $G$ has no vertices with no neighbors), then it is easy to see that every vertex cover $C$ of $G$ is also a dominating set. Indeed, every vertex $v\in V$ is either in $C$, or has a neighbor in $C$.
Therefore, it may be tempting to define a reduction from the vertex cover problem, denoted $\text{VC}$, that given $(G, k)$ outputs the same graph after removing all isolated vertices and the same $k$. Note, however, that the latter reduction does not work as you can, for example, consider the case where $G$ is a triangle: every vertex cover of $G$ must have at least two vertices, yet any vertex alone defines a dominating set. In other words, the resulting graph $G'$ is such that $(G', 1)\in \text{DS}$, yet $(G, 1)\notin \text{VC}$.
Although the above reduction does not work, it is in the right direction and can be fixed as follows. One can add, for every edge $\{u, w\}\in E$, a new vertex $v_{\{u, w\}}$, and two new edges $\{v_{\{u, w\}}, u\}$ and $\{v_{\{u, w\}}, w\}$. So the reduction essentially operates as follows. Given input $(G, k)$, we remove all isolated vertices from $G$, and for every edge $\{ u, w\}\in E$, we add a new vertex $v_{\{u, w\}}$ that is connected by an edge only to $u$ and $w$. We also output the same integer $k$.
The basic idea is that now if we have a dominating set $C$ of size at most $k$ in $G'$, then we can assume w.l.o.g that $C\subseteq V$; that is, it consists only of original vertices. Indeed, otherwise, if $C$ contains some new vertex $v_{\{ u,w\}}$, then we can remove it from $C$, and add to $C$ the vertex $u$ or the vertex $w$. Note that the latter does not increase the size of $C$, and $C$ remains a dominating set.
Now it is not hard to see that $C$ is also a vertex of the input graph $G$. Indeed, as $C$ is a dominating set in $G'$, then for every edge $\{u, w\}\in E$, it holds $v_{\{ w, u\}}$ is of distance at most one from $C$, and as $v_{\{ w, u\}} \notin C$, then $C$ must contain at least one of $w$ and $u$. So intuitively, by adding the new vertices and edges, we kind-of give "attention" to every edge $e$ in $E$ as the endpoints of $e$ are the closest vertices to the vertex $v_e$ in $G'$.
It is not hard to show that the other direction still holds, namely,  every vertex cover $C$ of size at most $k$ in $G$ is also a dominating set in $G'$ (note that in this case, we can assume w.l.o.g that $C$ has no isolated vertices of $G$), and I leave the details to you.

Heh, the same trick that shows that Hamiltonian cycle is NP-hard on chordless graphs (can be further improved to arbitrary girth) or that graph thickness is NP-hard to compute on bipartite graphs.

@rus9384 Good to know!
